# Call server method using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have an issue regarding to call a server method from Freemarker .
The following piece of code works on Google Chrome but not over IE :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     $('#uploadFileButton')[0].addEventListener('click', function (event) {
                    alert("here @ Upload event");
                        $('#form').attr('action', "[@spring.url '/test'/]");
                        $('#form').submit();
                        return false;
                    }, false);
 });
```

After investigation , I have found out that I should use attachEvent .
However , it still doesn't work over IE

Any tips !!

---

EDIT: Additional information incorrectly posted as an answer:

I just would like to update you with my latest status . I use the following :

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$('#uploadFileButton').click(function() {
    alert("here @ Upload event");
    $('#form').attr('action', "[@spring.url '/test'/]");
    $('#form').submit();
    alert("AfteZ Submit");
    return false;
});
```

});
The problem now that the two alerts I have is working fine . This means that the submit is not working properly .However this url was working on Chrome b4 I use the "Click" instead of "addEventListener" Any Tips !!

Comment: The error that this Jquery method doesn't call the server method

Comment: Retagged your question since it has nothing to do with either Spring MVC or FreeMarker.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function() {
     $('#uploadFileButton').click(function() {
        $('#form').attr('action', "[@spring.url '/test'/]").submit();
     });
});
```

If you're using jquery 1.6.1, then you should probably use `.prop()` instead of `.attr()`

Comment: Hello,
 I have added this upon your comments .
 I got the two alerts but nothing submits to the server !!
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#uploadFileButton').click(function() {
        alert("here @ Upload event");
         $('#form').prop('action', "[@spring.url '/test'/]");
        $('#form').submit();
  alert("After Submit");
        return false;
    });
});

Comment: Then I'm afraid we're going to need a little more info...  I'd try using the Developer Tools in IE (F12) and step through this code.  Make sure you have the form object and that the action is being updated.  Maybe you'll catch an error...

Comment: The Solutions is : $('#upload')[0].attachEvent('onclick', function (event) {
      $('#form').attr('action', "[@spring.url '/test/]");
      $('#form').submit();
      return false;
    });

Answer (score 0):

jQuery has itself ways for attaching click events in a crossbrowser way with the `click` function:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#uploadFileButton').click(function() {
        alert("here @ Upload event");
        $('#form').attr('action', "[@spring.url '/test'/]");
        $('#form').submit();
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: Still doesn't submit to server !!

Comment: The question is: the `alert` happened? If so, your problem about the event handler don't working on IE was solved, and that is what you pointed on your question. The form submitting is another thing and we would need view your HTML and your server-side method to understand why it isn't working...

Comment: This is the server side method :
 @RequestMapping(
            value = "test",
            method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView
    upload(@ModelAttribute(value = "formBean")
                                           formBean FormBean,
                                           BindingResult result) throws IOException {

     
     // Do smth
     
        return new ModelAndView("/test").
                addObject("formBean", formBean);
    }

Comment: Is your button inside a `<form id="form">`?

Comment: <form title="title" id="form" method="POST" action="#" submit="Test Ajax " cancel="Cancel" submitName="submit" cancelName="cancel" enctype="multipart/form-data" />

Comment: I think IE don't like selfclosing tags for `form`. And your #uploadFileButton would be inside it.

Comment: Actually it was just a typo :( -- <input type="submit" id="uploadFileButton" name="uploadFileButton" value="Upload"/><br/>

Answer (score 0):

The answer is :

```
$('#uploadFileButton')[0].attachEvent('onclick', function (event) {
      $('#form').attr('action', "[@spring.url '/evidence/metabolomicsDataset/uploadParameters'/]");
      $('#form').submit();
      return false;
    });
```

IE understands both "attachEvent" & "onclick" :)